# Passing char* to a function in combination with memcpy

Tags: c, char, stack, parameter-passing

usually a basic question, but maybe I am just too stupid. I try to pass an `char *` as output trought the parameter of a function. Inside the function I create a temporary `char *` which I want to `memcpy` to the address I've passed. Here is the code:

```
#define BLOCKSIZE=1024
int myFunction(char *s, char **out) {
  int i = strlen(s);
  *out = (char *)malloc(BLOCKSIZE);
  char tmp[BLOCKSIZE];

  strcpy(tmp, s);
  tmp[++i] = 0x0f;

  for(int i=strlen(s);i < BLOCKSIZE; i++) {
    tmp[i] = 0xcc;
  }

  memcpy(*out, tmp, BLOCKSIZE);

  return 0;
}

int main() {
  char *s = "Hello World";
  char *o = (char *)malloc(BLOCKSIZE);

  myFunction(s, &o);

}
```

The problem is, the stack gets corrupted after it jumps out of the function `myFunction`..

Is there another way to do it?

Thank you in advance!

Best,

**Update: Problem solved**
The for loop part `i < BLOCKSIZE` must be changed to `i < (BLOCKSIZE - 1)`.

Comment: Are you sure about the C++ tag? This looks like C. In C++ this would be far, far easier.

Comment: Pointless. With `std::string`, all these troubles simply don't exist. Or is it a tag error and you are doing C programming ? Then please edit tag.

Comment: Your code sample is bogus. `tmp[++i] = 0x0f;` `i` isn't declared at this point.

Comment: Aside from your Program having some serious flaws already pointed out by others, how do you determine that the stack is corrupted?

Comment: You're leaking memory by calling `malloc` twice

Comment: Yeah, sorry, forgot the `i` initialization in the snippet. I've not copied the original code. It's more a sample.

Comment: When I remove the second `malloc` the error still exists. It's Visual Studio which mentions the stack corruption by `Run-Time Check Failure - Stack around the variable 'tmp' was corrupted`

Answer (score 2):

Your first problem is that you `malloc` twice, before and in the function. The `malloc` outside the call (second line of `main`) is leaked.

The second problem (and this tells me you didn't even compile the code) is that you use `i` before defining it.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, fogot the `i` initialization in the snippet. Also if removing the second `malloc` it's failing with `Run-Time Check Failure - Stack around the variable 'tmp' was corrupted`

Comment: That's because of some bug in your actual code, a bug which isn't present in this snippet. We're not psychic.

Comment: I am really sorry, but this time it's the code. There is nothing more than the code in the snippet. Just the function name `myFunction` differs.. Nevertheless, I've solved my problem by myself. The for loop must be changed from `i<BLOCKSIZE` to `i<(BLOCKSIZE-1)`.

Comment: @Brady: The current code **still** can't compile, it fails on the very first line. `BLOCKSIZE`  has an initializer but no type. The loop length is perfectly OK. If you think you need one byte less, it's because you're treating the output as a string (not a block of bytes). A string would need one extra char for `\0`. But you shouldn't copy a string with `memcpy` in the first place.

Comment: @Brady. `(BLOCKSIZE-1)` Why do you think that would makes a difference? (Hint: It shouldn't...)